# Why do my print current day (objective-C language) gives different language (2)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have used this code to show current day name. When runned into XCode, it is displayed in english, but when runned onto the iPhone, it shows the result in danish.

So how I can fix it ?

```
-(NSString *)selectWeekDate:(NSDate*)date
{       
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *weekDay = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    //[dateFormat release];
    NSLog(@"%@", weekDay);
    return  weekDay; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the NSDateFormatter [locale](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLocale)

```
- (void)setLocale:(NSLocale *)locale
```

You can make an english locale like this

```
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"] autorelease]; // for brits
NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]; // for americans
// etc...
```